# How to import custom modules to babel-jest tests using npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm creating a web app using npm. I'm trying to run unit tests of my custom module.

To begin with, the command I use to generate the issue:

```
vue-cli-service test:unit
```

And the error I get:

```
FAIL  tests/unit/js/myModule.spec.js
 ● Test suite failed to run

   .../tests/unit/js/myModule.spec.js:1
   ({"Object.<anonymous>":
     function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest)
   {import MyModule from "@/js/myModule.js";                                               
           ^^^^^^^^

   SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

My project's structure related to the problem looks like this:

```
.
├── jest.config.js
├── src
│   ├── js
│   │   └── myModule.js
└── tests
    └── unit
        └── js
            └── myModule.spec.js
```

In my `package.json`:

```
{
   "devDependencies": {
      "babel-jest": "^24.7.1"
   }
}
```

Body of `myModule.js`:

```
class MyModule {
    static method(){}
}

export default MyModule
```

And in body of `myModule.spec.js` I call:

```
import MyModule from "@/js/myModule.js";
```

What could be causing this error? I'm using the same line to import `myModule` in `src/js/otherModule.js` and there's no problem with that. Could this be related to using babel?

Also, please tell me if any more files/configs (jest, babel) are needed here to grab a wider view of the problem.

Comment: Where's your `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` file? Looks like you are transpiling `src/*` but you aren't transpiling `tests/*`

Comment: In `babel.config.js`, there are presets `@vue/app` and `@babel/preset-env`, also three plugins: `add-module-exports`, `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`, `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`

Comment: I'm far from a knowledgeable source on this, but the problem is that your `src/*` files are being transpiled, even when testing, but your spec files aren't. Where is the `babel.config.js` file located - it should be in the root.

Comment: It is in the root. Also, in the root dir, there's `jest.config.js` in which I have   transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$':
      'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest'
  },

Comment: What's the `babel.config.js` look like, and are there any other `babel.config.js` files in your tests directory?

Comment: Because I'm not an expert on it, [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3202) may help you as well! Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using

```
const MyModule = require('@/js/myModule')
```

and changing exporting module to

```
module.exports = MyModule;
```

solved the issue.